# Can we manage Trigger recursion in Platform events

Tags: platform-event, recursion

I have a scenario where I have to keep 2 objects in sync.

When Object_A is updated, i need to update Object_B. When Object_B is updated, i need to update Object_A.

I can do it using trigger and avoid recursion using static fields.

I would like to do the same using platform events. Is it possible to avoid recursion in such a scenario. I tried static variables to avoid recursion but without any success.
Does anybody if we can use platform events in such scenario and avoid recursion ?

***Account Trigger***

Create platform event PE1 to update opportunity

***PE1 trigger***

```
if(!avoidRecursive.updateAccount){
          avoidRecursive.updateOpportunity = true;
    update Opportunity
    }
```

***Static Class containing variable to avoid recursion***

```
public class avoidRecursive {

     public static boolean updateAccount = false;
    public static boolean updateOpportunity = false;
 }
```

***Opportunity Trigger***

Create platform event PE2 to update Account

***PE2 trigger***

```
if(!avoidRecursive.updateOpportunity){
        avoidRecursive.updateAccount = true;
        update Account  
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform triggers execute in a separate transaction from the one that publishes so the logic mentioned above won't work as static variables would be reset.

With platform events you will need additional error handling in case the updates fail. There are other options which can help you avoid this complexity.

1. Using a scheduled batch.
2. Use process builder if your logic is not complex and the account/opportunity to update are related.
3. Use triggers directly without platform events.

**Option 1**: Would to use separate event definition for this update and don't publish these 2 specific definition events if the current user is Automated User or the one defined in [Platform event subscriber configuration.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm)

**Option 2**: You can something like this:

Check recursion variable to trigger on the actual object and mark the recursion variable as true in Platform Event trigger.

This would be somewhat complex for anyone who is going to see this code for first time as it requires you to memorize the state of variables in mind to understand the functioning.

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {
    if (!RecursionClass.opportunityTriggerExecuted) {
        // Publish platform event to update account here
        EventBus.publish(List<PlatformEventAccount__e>); // Use list name here
    }
}


trigger PlatformEventAccountTrigger on PlatformEventAccount__e (after update) {
    if (!RecursionClass.accountTriggerExecuted) {
        RecursionClass.accountTriggerExecuted = true;
        // Do processing
        update accounts;
    }
}

trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    if (!RecursionClass.accountTriggerExecuted) {
        // Publish platform event to update opportunities here
        EventBus.publish(List<PlatformEventOpportunity__e>); // Use list name here
    }
}

trigger PlatformEventOpportunityTrigger on PlatformEventOpportunity__e (after update) {
    if (!RecursionClass.opportunityTriggerExecuted) {
        RecursionClass.opportunityTriggerExecuted = true;
        // Do processing
        update opportunity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manjit. Your option 2 worked.
I can't use Process builder since the objects involved are unrelated.